# Whats the difference between telegram user messages and bots?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, mql5

I have a telegram bot recieving webhooks which work. But a MT5 EA does not trigger trades. (Left side of image). But when I type manually in the same telegram bot, the trades do work. (Right side of image)

[Image of telegram bot, differences in responce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkBWW.png)

I want to learn and be able to fix this myself, but I don't know where to look. Just after a little guidance. Can send any code, but did not want to post unessessary/large amounts. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The bot will not receive any messages send by (another) bot.

So the command send by the bot will not trigger any action on the bot itself.

When you copy, paste and send the command, the bot will actual receive it and execute the correct handler.

---

Long story short; Bots can never trigger an other bot action.